# Equivalence of homology theories via acyclic models

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

I'm looking for a proof of "any two homology theories are equivalent" (obviously with some other hypothesis) via the Acyclic Models Theorem. I know that this is an application of the Acyclic Models Theorem but I couldn't find any documentation about it. Does anyone know some references where I can find this proof?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Spanier's *Algebraic Topology* maybe has this.